# Homogeneous and consistent statements over a Field.

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to confirm if my answers to the following statements are correct:

**For any positive integers m and n and for a system of m linear equations in n variables over the field $F$, if the linear system is homogeneous, then its solution set contains $(x,...,x_n) = (0,...,0)$.**

This is true because, in homogenous systems $b = 0$. $b$ as in the $b$ in $Ax=b$ where A is a matrix. But how do I prove this apart from restating the definition?

**For any positive integers m and n and for a system of m linear equations in n variables over the field $F$, if the linear system is nonhomogeneous, then the system is consistent.**

This is False because a nonhomogeneous system is not always consistent because the system can have no solution which makes it inconsistent. But how do I prove this apart from restating the definition?

**For any positive integers m and n and for a system of m linear equations in n variables over the field $F$, its solution set is not equal to $F^n$.**

I am not sure where to start here??

**For any positive integers m and n and for a system of m linear equations in n variables over the Field $F$, if $(x_1,...,x_n) = (0,...,0)$ is an element of the solution set of the linear system, then the linear system is homogeneous.**

False because all solutions need to equal $0$.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do to these statements? Is it true/false, or is it always/sometimes/never? It seems to be true/false. In that case three is false because the zero system of equations has solution set $F^n$. Though this depends on your definition of linear equation/system of linear equations.

Comment: Also four is true. If $0$ is a solution, then the system $Ax=b$ has solution $0$, so $0=A0=b$. Thus $b=0$, so by definition, the system is homogeneous.

Comment: Yes, they are true or false questions.

Comment: @jgon Four makes more sense now.

Comment: @jgon But for three, what does $F^n$ mean here?

Answer (score 1):

For one: just state that the product of any number times zero is zero, and the sum of zero with zero is zero...

For two: Give an example: for any $\;m\;$, the non-homogeneous system system in $\;n\;$ unknowns $\;\overbrace{x_m=1, x_1=0,...,x_1=0, x_1=1}^{m\;\text{equations}}\;$ is inconsistent

As above, but but with $\;m\;$ quations as follows $\;0=0\;$ : the set of solutions is $\;\Bbb F^n\;$

Last one: true, because of the same reason as in number one.

Fill in details and get your complete set of reasonings.